# Go through files in a folder

Tags: makefile

Here is the part of my makefile to compile a project in OCaml and generate a binary:

```
all:     $(CMX_DOMAIN) analyze
         export OCAMLRUNPARAM=b
```

I would like `make tests` to do the follows:

1. Compile the project
2. run `./$(BIN)` to each files in the folder `tests/`

Could anyone tell me how to write this part of `tests` in makefile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
tests: all
        for f in tests/*; do ./$(BIN) $$f || exit 1; done
```

?  Or do you need more than that?